# Cómo puedo filtrar un array de objetos con angular

Tags: angular, firebase, typescript

En el archivo `data.service.ts` tengo

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

// firebase
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) { }

  getData(){
    return this.firestore.collection('data').snapshotChanges();
  }
}
```

Y en el `archivo.component.ts` aqui quisiera aplicarle el filtrado,

```
export class SectionLunchComponent implements OnInit {

  public data = [];
  constructor(
    private DataApiService: DataApiService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.DataApiService.getData().subscribe((dataSnapshot) => {
      this.data = [];
      dataSnapshot.forEach((menuData: any)=> {
        this.data.push({
          data: menuData.payload.doc.data()
        })
      })
    })
  }

}
```

No entiendo muy bien como puedo hacerlo, he estado revisando información sobre pipe y hasta le aplique filter en el component.ts.
Ademas use value en lugar de snapshot pero la gran diferencia es que uno me imprime en antalla y el otro no.
help!!

Comment: has intentado ver console.log que valores va tomando tus variables, tambien otra opcion es debuguear el codigo en el navegador colocando breakpoints en esa parte del codigo :)

Answer (score 2):

El método filter te genera un nuevo array, tomado del array principal, con los elementos que cumplan una condición. Es mejor explicado con un Ejemplo.

```js
    let personas = [
      { nombre: 'Juan', edad: 18, pais: 'Colombia' },
      { nombre: 'Eduardo', edad: 25, pais: 'Ecuador' },
      { nombre: 'Diana', edad: 15, pais: 'Colombia' },
    ];

    console.log('Personas:\n',personas);

    let mayoresDeEdad = personas.filter(persona => persona.edad >= 18);

    console.log('Personas mayores de Edad:\n', mayoresDeEdad);

    let colombianos = personas.filter(persona => persona.pais === 'Colombia');

    console.log('Personas de Colombia:\n',colombianos);
```

Comment: Por favor coloca el código como texto y no como imagen

Answer (score -2):

Puedes utilitzar la función filter:

```js
dataSnapshot.filter(menuData => menuData.x === 'condicion');
```

Comment: Hola ¿que realiza la función filter?, te sugiero agregar esa información en la respuesta para que sea de ayuda a más usuarios de la comunidad, revisa [answer], saludos!